# Rate limiting with lua

Tags: lua, rate-limiting

We have implemented redis based rate limiting for our web service which has been taken from [here](https://www.dr-josiah.com/2014/11/introduction-to-rate-limiting-with_26.html). I am duplicating the relevant code here.

```
local limits = cjson.decode(ARGV[1])
local now = tonumber(ARGV[2])
local weight = tonumber(ARGV[3] or '1')
local longest_duration = limits[1][1] or 0
local saved_keys = {}
-- handle cleanup and limit checks
for i, limit in ipairs(limits) do

local duration = limit[1]
longest_duration = math.max(longest_duration, duration)
local precision = limit[3] or duration
precision = math.min(precision, duration)
local blocks = math.ceil(duration / precision)
local saved = {}
table.insert(saved_keys, saved)
saved.block_id = math.floor(now / precision)
saved.trim_before = saved.block_id - blocks + 1
saved.count_key = duration .. ':' .. precision .. ':'
saved.ts_key = saved.count_key .. 'o'
for j, key in ipairs(KEYS) do

    local old_ts = redis.call('HGET', key, saved.ts_key)
    old_ts = old_ts and tonumber(old_ts) or saved.trim_before
    if old_ts > now then
        -- don't write in the past
        return 1
    end

    -- discover what needs to be cleaned up
    local decr = 0
    local dele = {}
    local trim = math.min(saved.trim_before, old_ts + blocks)
    for old_block = old_ts, trim - 1 do
        local bkey = saved.count_key .. old_block
        local bcount = redis.call('HGET', key, bkey)
        if bcount then
            decr = decr + tonumber(bcount)
            table.insert(dele, bkey)
        end
    end

    -- handle cleanup
    local cur
    if #dele > 0 then
        redis.call('HDEL', key, unpack(dele))
        cur = redis.call('HINCRBY', key, saved.count_key, -decr)
    else
        cur = redis.call('HGET', key, saved.count_key)
    end

    -- check our limits
    if tonumber(cur or '0') + weight > limit[2] then
        return 1
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to figure out the meaning of the comment **-- don't write in the past**
I don't see how a case would be possible where `old_ts` is greater than `now`
I have put logs all over the lua code but without any success.

At maximum `old_ts` can be equal to `saved.trim_before` which in turn can be equal to `now` if `precision` is 1 and `blocks` is 1. But not greater . 
It would be helpful if someone has insights on it.

Comment: There are two `for` loops in your code, but only one of them is being closed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Had missed one `end`.

Comment: Really dumb idea: what if the system time changes?

Comment: ...or maybe the "don't write in the past" check is for a case that never happens with the current code base, but was put in place in case future code could cause that.

Comment: In our web service we log rate limiting breaches. I am surprised to see that some breaches are from this part of the code as well.  That's driving my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the gist provided in the article

https://gist.github.com/josiahcarlson/80584b49da41549a7d5c

There is comment which asks

```lua
In over_limit_sliding_window_lua_, should

if old_ts > now then

at here be

if old_ts > saved.block_id then
```

And I agree to this, the `old_ts` is supposed to have the `bucket` and when the bucket jumps to the next slot, that is when `old_ts` will be greater then than the `block_id`